# iOS assembly code

Tags: ios, assembly, arm

I would like to try some ARM assembly code with apple iOS just for educational purpose. I would like to start with some in line code within Xcode.
My understanding is that I need to compile for a iOS device, for example for my iPhone, which means that I need to pay $99/year for membership.
I don't think I can use ASM assembly code with a iOS phone simulator.
I am having an hard time on finding examples, books or documentation on ARM assembly code in Xcode env with an iPhone.
Am I doing this wrong? Maybe iOS is not the most user friendly environment to learn ARM Assembly.

Comment: FWIW, here is a [collection of links](http://www.shervinemami.info/armAssembly.html) on writing assembly programs for iOS. I seriously doubt the value of this exercise, other than educational and entertainment.

Comment: Writing assembly code for iOS/ARM requires an iOS device and a membership in the program. To get started, it may be enough to read the ARM code generated by the compiler, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166055/how-do-i-get-started-with-arm-on-ios

Comment: My blog post on timing of ARM asm under iOS provides a number of useful links and an example Xcode project that includes .s files attached to an Xcode project: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post10_arm_timing_framework/index.html

Answer (score 14):

Back up...

What are you trying to learn?  Arm assembly or iOS programming?  Pick one...

Do you have any assembly experience?

What is it you think you are wanting to learn in arm assembly?  Jump in and write some full blown gui applications?  You need to learn to put immediates in registers add and or and xor and save answers in registers. then read and write some memory locations.  Learn to use the stack, make calls, etc.  Then write your applications in C or whatever and use asm for hand tuning or use your asm skills to debug the compiler and or code.  Writing applications or operating systems, etc in asm is for folks who want to make a statement, or have a specific reason, not for educational purposes.

There is some leaning toward a unified ARM assembly language that works both on the ARM based cores and the thumb2 based cores.  Not for all of the assembly language needed but for places where you might want to write a module of code and not have to have a lot of if thumb elses littering the code.  You can certainly get your feet wet with that here and take some of that code straight to full 32 bit ARM instructions on some other platform.  thumbulator is thumb only, the common instruction set between the ARM based cores and the thumb2 based cores, basically it is the portable ARM instruction set, write the code once, it works on almost all of their cores.

If your goal is to learn iOS programming, get the kit or whatever and learn using whatever language they want you to learn, get proficient at that, learn the apis, etc.  Then if you do some of the assembler stuff above then you can start to think about making calls to asm functions or inline assembler, etc, from your iOS programs.  How much assembler, your choice.  I wouldnt expect to see applications written in assembler for that platform I would instead search for how do I call this assembly code from my ios application or how do I do inline assembly.  (dont learn inline assembly until you are good at real assembly).

There is no reason at all to pay for access to a simulator, there are many many arm simulators out there, one in mame, arms armulator in gdb and other places, a number of gameboy advance and nintendo ds simultators, etc, etc, etc.  Of course there is qemu-arm.  there are more simulators than you probably are willing to take the time to try, i am about 10 years or so into it myself and not tried them all.

learning assembly is not like C or python or java, I will write a minesweeper game to learn this language.  You are learning the mechanics of moving the bits around, small steps, not writing usable applications.  For example adding two 128 bit numbers using a 16 bit processor is a worthy assembly language project.  Multiplying two numbers, any size, with a processor without a multiply instruction, that is another assembler type learning project.  yes, I agree you CAN learn those things by calling asm from an iOS application, but if you dont already have the iOS developers kit and know how to write iOS applications, you have a lot of learning to do before you start thinking about assembler.

If I am way off the mark with what you were asking, no problem I will gladly remove this answer...

Comment: Please read the original question and answer that. Original question asked what was required to write assembler in iOS, not if writing assembler is a good way to learn programming in iOS. I believe our place as experienced technology professionals on Stackoverflow is not to challenge the reasons for doing something, but is just to help the OP achieve what he asked.

Comment: Tomm P:  Well said!   (50+ year coder)

Comment: 35+ year coder.  "Maybe iOS is not the most user friendly environment to learn ARM Assembly.".  I think I am right on point with this answer.  Please re-read the question.

Answer (score 2):

Even without a code signing cert, I think you should be able to go to the scheme pop-up menu (the right side of it) and choose "iOS Device"

Once you do that, then you can choose any .c or .m (or .cpp or .mm) file in your project, open the assistant editor, and choose "Assembly" from the assistant editor jumpbar. Then you can see your source code and assembly code side by side.

Or you can just go to Product menu and Generate Output -> assembly

You may find it easier to start with C code, where the function calls will be much easier to follow initially than Objective-C method calls.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an ARM development kit with a Linux-based programming toolkit. You can then install VirtualBox on your Mac, create a Linux virtual machine and install the ARM development tools on the virtual Linux machine.  Make sure that when you buy an ARM dev kit, it comes with the ARM cpu, complete dev/test board, USB cables for software transfer/debugging and the complete Linux toolchain.  You can find such kits for less than $99.

Comment: How does that help him run any of his code on his iPhone as a binary?

Comment: It doesn't, but if he wants to write and debug ARM assembly code he will go much farther with a proper ARM dev kit.  And if he doesn't like it, he can resell it unlike his iOS developer membership.

Comment: If he is not already an iOs developer that is not the platform to start with. I agree with Jacek.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick introduction to ARM assembly and reverse engineering: http://yurichev.com/writings/RE_for_beginners-en.pdf

Comment: you gave what I was looking for, thnx dude